# How to use a label, but then filter out the extensions?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels

I'm setting up a new website/community and want to use my G-Mail account as the primary address. The problem is that I'm going to have a lot of emails coming through from different sources for different reasons, and I'd like to effectively sort my inbox, but how can this be done?

Here's an example of what I will more than likely have:

```
my.business@gmail.com
```

To make things a bit clearer, I could then split it up for incoming messages:

```
my.business+service.one@gmail.com
```

I could then apply a filter/subfilter which could be `Sevice/One`.

Now this would be fine but I'd like to make it a little more dynamic by having further extensions:

```
my.business+service.one.contact@gmail.com
my.business+service.one.billing@gmail.com
my.business+service.one.twitter@gmail.com
etc
```

So as you can imagine, I'd have to set up multiple sub-sub-labels in order to effectively filter out incominmg messages for each.

Is there an easier way, where I can use the `Service/One` label, but then filter out the extensions,

`( contact/billing/twitter/etc )`?

Comment: Have you tried the solution offered? Did it work for you? If not we should try finding out why. If yes, as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well -. ([Why vote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)?)

Comment: No your answer didn't work as it was just highlighting what I had already done. I'm looking for a way to filter emails sent to the `socialmedia` filter .

Comment: _"...it was just highlighting..."_ **That means it works**. That is how it is supposed to work. First "highlight" (which is actually find) and then create the filter. Do you know how to create a filter? You have to press the dropdown arrow on the right hand side and choose to create the filter.

Comment: I have created a filter ( in this case `socialmedia` ) - I want to be able to then filter out the messages that come from Twitter, hence the `?ref=twitter` - As explined in my original question. I don't want to have to create additional secondary filters for each social netowrk that I sign up for.

Comment: What I'm wanting to do is not the same a searching for messages from twitter.com - More about being able to sign up to twitter using the address `address+socialmedia.twitter@gmail.com`, and have it be listed under the SocialMedia label, but then filtered as Twitter, some how!

Comment: _"...but then filtered as Twitter, some how"_. Well.... **That is just not possible**. Each filter acts autonomously and only and never before the final step. That is why you will need -maybe similar but definately- unique filters. One for `address+socialmedia.twitter@gmail.com`, one for `address+socialmedia.facebook@gmail.com` etc. You do not need to have `address+socialmedia.twitter@gmail.com`. Just `address+twitter@gmail.com`. It will do the same job.

Comment: And finally use [sublabels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IS0cK.png) for each network.

Comment: I'm still not sure we're on the same page. I've edited my question a bit if it helps

Comment: We are on the same page and I'm afraid no matter how many times you rephrase it, the answer will still be [the same](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/133295/how-to-create-filters-for-incoming-g-mail-messages?noredirect=1#comment121794_133295).

Comment: Ok, so if the simple answer to this is **No**, what is a good alternative solution that doesn't result in having to set up tons of labels, sub labels, and potentially sub labels of sub labels?

Answer (score 1):

Filters using "src" are not supported.

I believe what you are looking for is a filter like:


```
from:(@twitter.com) to:(address+twitter@gmail.com)
```


This actually reads:


```
All (and any) incoming emails from: "twitter.com"
To: "address+twitter@gmail.com"
```

From then on, you choose your desired actions.

In any case, I would also recommend having a look at the [Gmail Operators](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190).

> **EDIT** (following your comment [*...it was just highlighting...*](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/133295/categorising-incoming-g-mail-messages?noredirect=1#comment121776_133295))

After you make the search using the above given filter, **you have to create your "permanent" filter** by first clicking on the **little arrow on the right side**,

[image]

and then, after further adjusting your search, click on the **bottom button "Create filter"**.

[image]